# XSLT target specific string before closing tags

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am currently trying to add a new attribute to an element but the value needs to come from the data itself and I have no clue how to target it as the text value can happen in 2 different places.

My input XML is as following:

Case 1

```
<div>
   <title/>
   <p>This is an example where the string is being used in the text (0123-45-6789) and how a sentence can look like. (0123-45-6789)</p>
</div>
```

Case 2

```
<div>
   <title>This is an example title. (0123-45)</title>
   <p>This is an example sentence.</p>
</div>
```

Target

```
<div id="0123-45">
    <title>This is an example title. (0123-45)</title>
    <p>This is an example sentence.</p>
</div>
```

The string I need is the one between the brackets and it can consist of 2 digits, 4 digits, 6 digits or 10 digits. As the string can also be used in text I can only target the ones that are before the closing tag

and .

I already tried to use `analyze-string` with `regex` but ended up targeting all of the strings instead of the ones I need.

Is there any way this can be done in XSLT? Thanks in advance to point me in the right direction!

Kind regards

Comment: In Case 1 you have 2 times the same sequence to capture(0123-45-6789). Are they always the same and if not, which one should be used?

Comment: Sorry was off sick hence the late reply. No they can differ and always the last one should be used. They will always be at the end of a sentece just before the closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
    <div id="{replace(., '.*\((.*)\).*', '$1')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```